# if a public key cannot decrypt the cipher text, then how can a private key?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, hash

I understand the "public" part of public key cryptography. Not the "private" part.

For example, let's say our public key is %7 (modulo 7). And the message to be encrypted is 22.

And we know that 22 % 7 = 1

Here, 1 is the encrypted message.

The reason why public keys work is that despite knowing the public key (%7) and the encrypted message (1), I cannot confirm that the original message was 22.

So, this begs the question, how does the private key figure out that the original message was 22?

Comment: You are confusing hashing with asymmetric cryptography. Hashes are not reversible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Encryption

Comment: This isn't an encryption scheme. At all. It's not an encryption scheme for the precise reason that you can't decrypt anything.

Comment: @cpast Some public key cryptosystems (take RSA for example) can be used to encrypt.

Comment: @Cthulhu But this is not RSA. The scheme in the question is not an encryption scheme.

Comment: @cp but that's because OP just doesn't know what they are and is trying to invent algorithm.

Comment: @Cthulhu I read the Wiki example you provided. It's a good example. But... in the example, n = 3233, d = 2753 and d is hidden. If we know that n=3233, there cannot be many values for d that won't give gibberish. My point being, that it should be possible to compute d. My original question still stands: if a modulo (public key) produces a result that cannot be reverse engineered, then how is the private key able to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you presented is not an encryption scheme, you just took a number and modded it by 7. This can not be an encryption scheme because there is more than one "message" which will produce the same "cipher text", for example:

- the message **22** produces the cipher text 22 % 7 = **1**
- the message **29** produces the same cipher text 29 % 7 = **1**
- the message **36** produces the same cipher text 36 % 7 = **1**
- . . .

So your question:

> how does the private key figure out that the original message was 22?

It doesn't because for the cipher text "**1**", there are an **infinite** number of possible original messages.

---

What you have looks kinda similar to RSA, so I'm guessing that you read something about RSA and are trying to work through the math. There's a nice easy sample calculation of RSA [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/honors/soln.html) that you could try working through.

For a more detailed description of the math of RSA, you can go to the [wikipedia page for RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Encryption).

---

Edit: in comments you said:

> if a modulo (public key) produces a result that cannot be reverse engineered, then how is the private key able to do it?

Alright, let's walk through that example of RSA.

- You choose two primes, let's take **p = 3**, and **q = 11**
- You compute n as **n =** p * q = 3 * 11 = **33**
- You compute **φ(n) =** (p-1)*(q-1) = 2 * 10 = **20**
- You choose a **public exponent e** such that 1 < e < φ(n), and that e and n are coprime. **e = 7** will do.
- You choose a **private exponent d** such that (d * e) % φ(n) = 1. **d = 3** will work since (3 * 7) % 20 = (21) % 20 = 1

Now your **public key is (7, 33)**, (e, n), and your **private key is (3, 33)**, (d, n).

Ok, now let's say that you want to encrypt the **plaintext message "22"**, as in your question. The encryption calculation is: m^e % n = c, where m is the original message and c is the ciphertext, so 22^7 % 33 = 22 (heh, that's a coincidence), so the **encrypted message is "22"**.

Now, the person who has the private exponent d can decrypt the ciphertext by calculating c^d % n = m, is our example 22^3 % 33 = 22.